# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skmultilearn' Jupyter

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

Tried cloning git to Jupyter folder on Windows. No progress.
I have installed SKMultilearn in the same folder as Jupyter.

```
ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-b987f02e7825> in <module>()
5 return_indicator = 'sparse', allow_unlabeled = False)
6
----> 7 from skmultilearn.adapt import MLkNN
8
9 classifier = MLkNN(k=20)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skmultilearn'
```

Comment: How did you install `skmultilearn`? Did you use `pip` or `conda`?

Comment: @PrasadK I used `pip` like its mentioned on the website

Comment: What is probably happening is that your jupyter notebook is using a different python interpreter than the one for which pip installed the skmultilearn package.

Comment: Run `import sys; sys.executable` in your jupyter notebook to figure out which python is being used. Can you post the output of that command?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and couldn't find a solution. Remember, you must have installed **skmultilearn** first from cmd, `pip install scikit-multilearn`. If you have done this and still Jupyter Notebook is saying **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skmultilearn'**, then my solution is for you.

I tried and managed to find an easy solution. I hope that you might have found a solution as this question was asked 3 years ago. I am posting this because many new users will be facing this issue.

1. Open **Jupyter Notebook** `terminal` and go into `python`.
2. Type, `help('modules')`. You will get a list of all packages available to you. 99% chance is that you will not find `skmultilearn` in that list.
3. Now, go to **command prompt** aka `cmd`.
4. Type, `pip3 install ipykernel --upgrade`, then `py -3 -m ipykernel install --user`, you will get this, `Installed kernelspec python3 in C:\Users\MC\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\python3`.
5. Now type, `pip install scikit-multilearn`. It will say `Requirement already satisfied: scikit-multilearn in c:\python396\lib\site-packages (0.2.0)`
6. Good now type, `pip3 install jupyter`.
7. Then, again install **pandas** and **seaborn** as your need, `pip install pandas` and `pip install seaborn`.

Enjoy, issue resolved. You will not face this error :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that skmultilearn has been correctly installed? It does not depend on the subdirectory where you did the installation.

Open a terminal window in your Jupyter browser, go into python

> ipython

and then check out the modules that has been installed:

> [1] help('modules')

You will get a list of all packages available to you. skmultilearn should be in the list if it was correctly installed.

Answer (score 0):

pip install scikit-multilearn

```html
pip install scikit-multilearn
```

Comment: This has been already suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70233495/18145256).